# CRM 2011 Workflow not updating field

Tags: field, workflow, dynamics-crm, crm, updating

I have a simple workflow that runs on Create. If field X is yes, change Allow Email to Allow.

I have also created a personal view with criteria Fields X = Yes and Allow Email = Do No Allow. This is to give me list of contact that missing out.

Looking at last 7 days records, everyday this workflow runs on around 600 new contacts and updates fields as expected. But I also noticed that small number of Contacts (about 30ish per day) do not get their Allow Email field updated to Allow even when they meet the criteria of the if condition.

At this point I checked at the WF history and very strangely it shows that the field should have been modified. (see screen shot)[image]

- Workflow did fire off
- This contacts are not modified by any process or individual since the workflow had run
- Workflow shows the usual green tick indicating that it did meet the criteria
- Same workflow also updates 'Preferred language' and that seems to have updated fine for these contacts.
- I have also double checked the Update property to make sure it set correctly.

Has anyone else seen this? This makes WF not 100% reliable for me!

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow runs on Create.

If the record is created with Field X to No the workflow doesn't change the Allow value.

If a user change the Field X value to Yes after the record is created, you have the situation with records Field X Yes and Do Not Allow.

You wrote:

> This contacts are not modified by any process or individual since the
>   workflow had run

to confirm this, did you check that the ModifiedOn date equals CreatedOn date? I suggest to turn on audit for Field X.

My guess is that you didn't set your workflow to run also when the Field X value change (and it should)

Comment: Agree to Guido, Most probable case is that switch on the workflow when that field gets modified.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have checked the Modified On date/time and it matches with the WF time. Also, the field X never gets changed manually or by any process. This field is something that is mapped from the shop system. However, i have added the on change event for this field in the workflow to make sure. For last week this number of failed wf was around 30 but today it affected only 1 contact. May be because I got you guys on board :) thank you again. Mystery